# Google map is shown as blank when switching between tabs in ionic/angularJS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic + AngularJS + Cordova mobile app. I am using tabs in my app. In one of the tabs, I am showing a map to the user. I am using google maps V3 api for this. I am assigning the map to a div element.

```
var map = null
var mapOptions = {
      center: {lat: sourceLatitude, lng: sourceLongitude},
      zoom: 17,
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

I store user's markers. All works fine so far. I am able to store marker information and display the map as well in tab-one.

Now, in the other tab i.e tab-two. I display user's stored markers. So that, when user clicks any one of the stored markers, it should go back to the tab-one and should show the map with the selected marker displayed on it.
(I am using angularJS ui-router for handling different state transitions)

This is the point where I am facing an issue. When I go back to tab-one from tab-two, I get a blank map. I am not able to see the map being displayed. I know that the transition happens correctly as I have logging in place for that and rest other ui elements change. It is just the map which doesn't show up.

I read around SO and other sources, I see people have recommended the following:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

I have put the above statement in my angularJS controller, so that when it moves from tab-two to tab-one, it will try to resize or refresh the map. I get the below error in the console.

```
Error: a is undefined
_.C.hasListeners@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places:93:707
_.C.trigger@http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places:94:32
```

I read somewhere variable map should be global. Hence I tried putting map on $rootScope as well instead of using var

```
$rootScope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

But no luck :( in both the cases.

Has anybody seen this problem before? Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
V

Comment: I'd rather tag this question with `javascript` but I don't know which one you should remove.

Comment: done..tagged as javascript

Comment: Edited your tags too as I believe maps-api-3 in this case is quite important...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution :

```js
document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = ''; 
document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = '<div id="inner_map_div" style="width: 100%; height:400px"></div>';
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('inner_map_div'), mapOptions);
```

work for me :)

Comment: I tried your recommended solution. It didn't work for me :( I still continue to get blank map.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve my problem after struggling with it for 5 days.  Thought it would be good to post my solution here as well in case anyone finds himself/herself in the same situation.

I observed that map was getting correctly rendered when the controller was created and initialised the first time. The same controller was getting used when I was switching between the two tabs and there was no problem in displaying the map.

It was only when I clicked the stored marker in tab-two, it created a new controller which had a problem with rendering the map. I was changing the state on button click may be that was what creating a new instance of the controller.

So, what I did was applied my map controller to the body of the index.html

```
<body ng-app="storeMarkerApp" ng-controller="MapController">
```

so that the same controller is used in both the tabs and when I click on the stored marker button. This resolved the issue. The map is getting rendered correctly.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
V